# Destination with arguments or actions must have 'name' or 'id' attributes

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I created a global action with the Android Navigation Component and I'm getting the following error when compiling the code

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@id/homeEnumerationFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeEnumerationFragment"
    android:name="org.southasia.ghru.ui.homeenumeration.HomeEnumerationFragment"
    android:label="HomeEnumerationFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_enumeration_fragment"></fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/stationFragments"
    android:name="org.southasia.ghru.ui.station.StationFragment"
    android:label="StationFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/station_fragment"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/devicesFragment"
    android:name="org.southasia.ghru.ui.devices.DevicesFragment"
    android:label="DevicesFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/devices_fragment"/>
<action android:id="@+id/action_global_stationFragments3" app:destination="@+id/stationFragments"/>
```

The error:

```
Error: Destination with arguments or actions must have 'name' or 'id' attributes.
```

Answer (score 30):

To use global action you need to have an id for your navigation graph (currently it is not generated automatically).
Just add 'id' attribute to your navigation element, like this:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   app:startDestination="@id/homeEnumerationFragment"
   android:id="@+id/main">
```

Comment: once remove safearg dependany its same code woking fine

Comment: So navigation element 'id' needed only for safe arguments (i though for global actions it needed too).